# Shibboleth Authentication and Authorization via Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am stuck and can't find any tutorial or documentation for setting Shibboleth SSO with Spring Boot as SP for authentication and authorization. I want to authenticate user. The flow I want is: USER send api call to Spring Boot and then Spring Boot authenticate it with Shibboleth.

I have tried to setup Shibboleth IDP with apache Tomcat and getting it's metadata on localhost:8080/idp/shibboleth. But I don't know what to do next.